# Comparing two columns in pandas - error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, if-statement, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe called m which has three columns `a`, `b`, `c`. I want to compare the column `b` with `a`, `c` and put the values into column `d`.

```
a   b   c
1   5   7
2   7   8
3   1   9
4   8   6
```

But when I try this in the following code, I got the error as

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Code:

```
if m['b'] < m['a']:
    m['d'] = m['a']
elif m['d'] > m['c']:
    m['d'] = m['c'] 
else:
    m['d'] = m['b']
m
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The pandas docs explain it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html) (first result when I google the error) and there are many duplicate questions/answers that explain why the error arises on Stack Overflow already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m['d'] = np.where(m['b'] < m['a'], m['a'], np.where(m['b'] > m['c'], m['c'], m['b']) )
print m    
   a  b  c  d
0  1  5  7  5
1  2  7  8  7
2  3  1  9  3
3  4  8  6  6
```